# How to add a record to a database using id instead of changing them (javascript and php)?

Tags: php

How do I add a few records to a database using the id’s I had listed in phpMyAdmin. The problem is once I entered the id , it display the database but when I entered another id , it took out and change the value of the first id database I entered and replace it with the second id. What I want is to add the database one by one through each click but instead of replacing it, I would like to add them below after the first ID I entered earlier. This is what I’m working on so far.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Search data by its ID</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Search a single DATA</h1>
    <h2>Retrieve data from database</h2>

    <div class="container">
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Student ID" />
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search By ID" />

      </form>
      <table border="2" id="newton">
        <tr>

          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Returned Date</th>
        </tr><br><br>
        <?php
               $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "");
               $db = mysqli_select_db($connection,"myfirstdb");

               if(isset($_POST['search']))
               {
                   $id = $_POST['id'];

                   $query = "SELECT * FROM `table3` where id = '$id'";
                   $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
                   {
                       ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row ['product_name']; ?> </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row ['quantity']; ?> </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row ['returned_date']; ?> </td>

          </tr>

          <?php

                   }
               }
               
               
               ?>

      </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need an INSERT query to insert new data into the database. You'll need a blank form to enter the new details. While you're in there, consider changing the database table to have more useful names. What does `table3` store? Your form suggests that it stores student details, yet the column names suggest it stores product details. You might remember now, but you won't in two years when you need to do some quick maintenance changes.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following code can solve your problem. Although the student ID has nothing to do with the name of the product !!
you can use a session for this problem.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Search data by its ID</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
    <h1>Search a single DATA</h1>
    <h2>Retrieve data from database</h2>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Student ID" />
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search By ID" />

        </form>
        <table border="2" id="newton">
            <tr>

                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Returned Date</th>
            </tr><br><br>
            <?php
            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "");
            $db = mysqli_select_db($connection,"myfirstdb");

            session_start();

            if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = array();
            }
            

            if(isset($_POST['search']))
            {
                $id = $_POST['id'];

                array_push($_SESSION['id'],$id);
                $_SESSION['id'] = array_unique($_SESSION['id']);

                $id = implode(',',$_SESSION['id']);



                $query = "SELECT * FROM `table3` where id in ($id)";
                $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
                {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
          <?php echo $row ['product_name']; ?> </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row ['quantity']; ?> </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row ['returned_date']; ?> </td>


                    </tr>

                    <?php

                }
            }


            ?>

        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```